# Levenshtein distance symmetric?

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I was informed Levenshtein distance is symmetric. When I used google's diffMatchPatch tool which computes Levenshtein distance among other things, the results don't imply Levenshtein distance is symmetric. i.e Levenshtein(x1,x2) is not equal to Levenshtein(x2,x1). Is Levenshtein not symmetric or is there a problem with that particular implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just looking at the basic algorithm it definitely is symmetric **given the same cost for the operations** - the number of additions, deletions and substitutions to get from a word A to a word B is the same as getting from word B to word A.

If there is a different cost on any of the operations there can be a difference though, e.g. if addition has a cost of 2 and deletion a cost of 1 to get from `Zombie` to `Zombies` results in a distance of 2, the other way round would be 1 - not symmetric.

Answer (score 11):

The classical Levenshtein algorithm is symmetric - what is an insertion going from x1 to x2 is a deletion going from x2 to x1.

Unfortunately, the algorithm is O(length(x1) * length(x2)) . After a brief look at the google's library, it seems it tries some heuristics to assure that the runtime is not too big. I think there lies Your discrepancy.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the levenshtein distance is a distance in the proper sense, that is `dist(a,b)==dist(b,a)` is a part of the definition of a distance.  If a function does not have this property it is not a distance function.  This suggests a problem with that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Python] As pointed out by others, by definition, Levenshtein's is a proper distance.

I found the same issue with fuzzywuzzy library (A.K.A. thefuzz) using the `ratio` function:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

s1 = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit"""

s2 = """in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum."""

fuzz.ratio(s1, s2)
Out [1]: 15

fuzz.ratio(s2, s1)
Out [2]: 2
```

However, this doesn't happen when using `partial_ratio`:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio(s1, s2)
Out [3]: 20

fuzz.partial_ratio(s2, s1)
Out [4]: 20
```

So the problem might reside in the implementation or is an intended behavior of the `ratio` function, unfortunately there is no documentation for these functions.

The tricky part is that for many pairs of strings `ratio` gives the same result regardless of the order, that's why I had to use such large strings to find a proper example (yet it still happens with smaller strings).

Comment: fuzz.ratio is not symmetric when using thefuzz with difflib. However it is symmetric when used with python-Levenshtein (python-Levenshtein uses the Indel similarity, which is symmetric). fuzz.partial_ratio is not symmetric. It just swaps the strings if they have a different length. When using two strings of similar length you can run into cases where the results are not symmetric.

Answer (score -2):

please follow the code which I implemented myself

```java
public class ReadTextFile {

    static void readFile(String filepath){
        CharSequence sequence1 = null;
        CharSequence sequence2 = null;
        
        int levenshteinDistance = 0;
        
        String line1 = "";
        String line2 = "";
        int minLevenshteinDistance = -1;
        
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            String line = "";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(sequence1==null){
                    line  = line.split(" ")[1];
                    sequence1 = line;                   
                    
                    if((line=br.readLine())!=null){                 
                        line  = line.split(" ")[1];
                        sequence2 = line;                   
                    }
                }else{
                    sequence1 = sequence2;
                    line  = line.split(" ")[1];
                    sequence2 = line;                   
                }
                
                if(null!=sequence1 && null!=sequence2){
                    
                    levenshteinDistance = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(sequence1,sequence2);
                    
                    if(minLevenshteinDistance==-1){
                        minLevenshteinDistance = levenshteinDistance;
                        line1= sequence1.toString();
                        line2= sequence2.toString();
                    }else if(levenshteinDistance < minLevenshteinDistance){
                        minLevenshteinDistance = levenshteinDistance;
                        line1= sequence1.toString();
                        line2= sequence2.toString();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            br.close();
            System.out.println("line1 "+line1);
            System.out.println("line2 "+line2);
            System.out.println("minlevenshteinDistance " + minLevenshteinDistance);
        
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer `Is Levenshtein not symmetric or is there a problem with [Google's diffMatchPatch tool]?`